# How molarity and mass fraction are related?

Tags: concentration, density

> Concentrated sulfuric acid contains very little water, only $5\,\%$ by mass. It has a density of $\pu{1.84 g mL-1}$. What is the molarity of this acid?

I know to use the molarity $c$ is in $\pu{mol L^-1}$ and that the solution is $95\,\%$ acid and $5\,\%$ water by mass. I am just stuck trying to solve the problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_concentration#Related_quantities

Answer (score 1):

If the density of $95\%$ $\ce{H2SO4}$ is given as $\pu{1.84 g mL-1}$ and its molar mass is $\pu{98.08 g mol-1}$, you may do following conversion since units of molarity is $\pu{mol L-1}$ (suppose it is $M$):

$$ M = \frac{\pu{1.84 g}\text{ of solution }}{\pu{ mL}\text{ of solution }} \times \frac{\pu{95 g} \text{ of } \ce{H2SO4}}{\pu{100 g}\text{ of solution }} \times \frac{\pu{1000 mL}}{\pu{L}}\times \frac{\pu{1 mol}}{\pu{98.08 g}} = \pu{17.8 mol L-1}$$

Comment: @Karsten Theis: No, I just use the data given by OP.

Comment: 1840 g/L x  0.95 / 98.08 g/mol = 17.83 mol/L

Comment: @Karsten Theis: I made an error. Forgot it is $95\%$. Corrected it. Thanks for the careful reading.

Comment: $M$ is the standardized symbol for molar mass, not molarity. Also, what's with all the text in… a math formula? The unit symbol turns out to be $$\pu{mol \ce{H2SO4} L^-1 solution^-1}$$ which is nonsense.

Comment: @andselisk ♦: There were some confution of readers about unit conversion so I include the text for clarity.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne That's why it's advised to first solve the problem using symbolic algebra (following standard notations and defining lesser common variables), and only then plug in the numbers. That's how clarity is achieved. Mixing text and math is simply wrong.